# Cannot map USB device with the docker container on Linux

Tags: linux, usb, docker, docker-compose

I cannot map my usb device with the docker container.

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 nov 27 09:28 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

```
$ groups
adm dialout sudo audio kvm lpadmin docker
```

I mapped ttyUSB0 device in my docker compose file:

```
    devices:
      - /dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0
```

And this is the error when I run the container:

```
$ docker compose up
Error response from daemon: error gathering device information while adding custom device "/dev/ttyUSB0": no such file or directory
```

If I add the priviliged property to the compose file I can run the container but I get this error when serial port is used:

```
    priviliged: true
    devices:
      - /dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0
```

And this is the error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 325, in open
raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
```

If I run `docker compose up` with **sudo** all works correctly, so I think it’s just a permissions issue.

I can't figure out how to correctly map the USB device to the container.

Comment: I think the issue is correlate to docker desktop for Linux.